# Proving that $\|f\|_{\infty} = \|f\|_{\max}.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Here is the question:

> [image]

Where  $\|f\|_{\infty} $ is defined to be the infimum of the essential upper bounds for $f.$
 And a function $f$ is called essentially bounded provided there is some $M \geq 0,$ called an essential upper bound for $f,$ for which $|f(x)| \leq M $ for almost all $x \in E.$

But still, I do not know how to prove this $\|f\|_{\infty} = \|f\|_{max}$ where $\|f\|_{max} = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|.$ Could anyone help me in doing so, please?

Comment: Clearly, if $M > \|f\|_{\mathrm{max}}$ then $\mu(|f|>M) = 0,$ so $\|f\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_{\mathrm{max}}.$ If, reciprocally, $M < \|f\|_{\mathrm{max}},$ there exists some interval $\mathrm{J}$ with non-empty interior in which $M \leq f \leq \|f\|_{\mathrm{max}},$ thus $m(\mathrm{J}) > 0$ (assuming $m$ to be positive on every open set, like Lebesgue measure) and so $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{\mathrm{max}}.$ Q.E:D.

Comment: why it should be an interval ? and why we are sure of its existence in the second case? Is M the essential upper bound? are we obliged to use the Lebesgue measure to prove this?@WillM.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an interval, but any subset of $\mathbf{R}$ with non empty interior contains an open interval (by definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $\|f\|_{max}$ is well-defined (e.g. if $f$ is continuous), we have $\|f\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_{max},$ which follows from $$\{x \in [a,b] \mid |f(x)| > \|f\|_{max}\} = \emptyset$$

---

For a continuous function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, we can let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and then note that $$U = \{x \in [a,b] \mid |f(x)| > \|f\|_{max} - \varepsilon\}$$ is an open subset of $[a,b]$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$).  Since $f$ is continuous, $$f(c) = \|f\|_{max} > \|f\|_{max}-\varepsilon$$ for some $c \in [a,b]$, $U \ni c$ is nonempty, so $m(U) \neq 0$.  Therefore $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{max}-\varepsilon$.  Now taking $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ yields $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{max}$.

---

**Note:** I have assumed $m$ denotes a measure that satisfies $m(V) > 0$ for any nonempty open set $V$.  This is true, for instance, of the Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ and $a<b$.

Comment: Can you please explain the general idea of your proof in the second part?

Comment: In your fourth line, did you mean the first inequality to be strict ?

Comment: @Secretly In the first part, we show the max-norm, when well-defined, is an essential upper bound of $f$.  In the second part, we show no smaller real number is an essential upper bound when $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: As for your second question, I don't know which is the "fourth line, first inequality", so you may need to be more specific.  On re-reading my answer, though, I don't see any inequality I intended otherwise.

Comment: for almost all $x \in E$ how does this affect your proof in the first part and the second part?

Comment: what do you mean by the max-norm being "well defined" could you explain more please?

Comment: @Mathstupid That is the reason the argument in the second part is required to use the measure $m$.

Comment: I think the comment is referring to this inequality $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{max}-\varepsilon$ that it should be strict.

Comment: The max-norm of $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ requires the maximum of $f([a,b])$ to exist.  Not every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a maximum, so if that set doesn't have a maximum, the max-norm is not well-defined.  When $f$ is a continuous function, we have $f([a,b]) = [c,d]$ for some real numbers $c,d$ so the max-norm is defined to be $d$.

Comment: but continuous functions on closed intervals always attains maximum.

Comment: Yes.  Did you even finish reading my previous comment before responding?

Comment: so in our problem the max norm is well defined .... correct?

Comment: @Secretly Yes, certainly.  I actually had added some more to my answer to clarify it's well-defined for continuous $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why $\epsilon$ tends to $0^+$ and not only $0$?