# Understanding why $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{\max}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

Here is the link for the proof:

[Proving that $\|f\|_{\infty} = \|f\|_{\max}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591114/proving-that-f-infty-f-max?noredirect=1#comment7383243_3591114)

And here is the proof:

For a continuous function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, we can let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and then note that $$U = \{x \in [a,b] \mid |f(x)| > \|f\|_{\max} - \varepsilon\}$$ is an open subset of $[a,b]$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$).  Since $f$ is continuous, $$f(c) = \|f\|_{\max} > \|f\|_{\max}-\varepsilon$$ for some $c \in [a,b]$, $U \ni c$ is nonempty, so $m(U) \neq 0$.  Therefore $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{\max}-\varepsilon$.  Now taking $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ yields $\|f\|_\infty \geq \|f\|_{\max}$.

**My question is:**

1-I am not sure why he took $f(c) = \|f\|_\infty$ ?

2- Also, it is not so clear for me the general idea of the proof of this direction. Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Do you mean why he took $f(c)=\|f\|_{max}$?

Comment: No,I mean  in the line before last after the word therefore he put $\|f\|_{\infty}$  instead of the $f(c)$ that was in the proceeding inequality.@MaximGilula

Comment: I see. They used a fact about inequalities; they didn't take $f(c)$ to actually equal $\|f\|_{\infty}.$ See below. $a>b$ and $b>c$ implies $a>c$ and that's what happened here.

Comment: Not $\|.\|_{\max}$ I said  $\|.\|_{\infty}$ @MaximGilula

Comment: Typo. Fixed....

Comment: By the way, in general it's good practice to not take things 100% literally, as textbooks make mistakes as well. Having such a habit might make for less confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-They didn't. They took $f(c)=\|f\|_{\max}$ to show $U$ is nonempty. If $U$ was empty, the argument wouldn't work since we wouldn't know there was some $x$ such that $f(x)>\|f\|_{\max}-\varepsilon$ and therefore wouldn't be able to argue

$$(\|f\|_\infty \ge f(c)) \text{ and } (f(c)>\|f\|_{\max}-\varepsilon) \text{ implies } (\|f\|_\infty \ge \|f\|_{\max}-\varepsilon).$$

2- The general idea happens frequently in analysis. If you want to show $a\ge b,$ but it's too hard for whatever reason to do it directly, you can try to show that $a\ge b-\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0,$ which is what happened here. The next part is figuring out how to write that properly. For example, defining that set $U$ and showing it's nonempty.

Comment: And why is this $\|f\|_\infty \ge f(c))$ true ?

Comment: Is it by definition of $\|f\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: Almost by definition. It's true for continuous functions, but it's not true by definition in general. What makes it work for continuous functions is $m(U)$ is nonzero (then just check the definition of sup norm).